# Using COM-Interface in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, vba, com

I was using VBA platform to connect 3rd part application named Simpack COM-Interface with below code;

```
Dim Srv As Object
Dim Mdl As Object
Dim modelname As String

Sub GetSimpackModel()
modelname = "myModel.spck"
Set Srv = CreateObject("Simpack.Gui.2018x")
Set Mdl = Srv.Spck.openModel(modelname)
End Sub
```

After that i have a chance to use Simpack's own classes in my project.

In VB.NET i'm using below code

```
Option Explicit On

Imports simpackcomguiLib

Module Module1

    Dim Srv As SpckCOMApp                                    'Define SRV variable as SpckCOMApp
    Dim Mdl As IScrModel                                           'Define Mdl variable as Model

    Sub GetConnect()
        Srv = New simpackcomguiLib.SpckCOMApp
        Mdl = Srv.Spck.openModel("myModel.spck")
    End Sub
End Module
```

This VB.NET code also works, i can open the program from VB.NET and access the Simpack's COM classes.

But when i open the Simpack with VBA, Simpack GUI works properly but when i opened with VB, Simpack's GUI getting freeze.

Do you think is there anything that i missed on COM-connection or am i using a wrong method?

My main question about this topic is; i realized a COM-Class item under Visual Studio. I would like to know if somebody have experience where/when do you recommend to use this ComClass item ?

Comment: Your code seems ok. That could be related to the way threads work in your app (STA, etc..) But, you should contact the vendor.

Comment: You could try run the module sub in a different thread, that may help :)

Comment: @Jaxi sorry i didn't understand very well do you mean seperate opening model process another thread ?

Comment: Run `Getconnect()` in a new thread is what i mean :)

Comment: @Jaxi i think you're right when i searched on internet about my problem can be solved by multithreading but i didn't succeeded. Could you please show me as an anser how can i apply your suggestion i can try and vote your answer.

Answer (score 0):

As requested, how to multithread this :) I'm not sure where your Main() is though so you'll have to replace your current `GetConnect()` call with the following:

```
Dim NewThread = New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf GetConnect)
NewThread.Start()
```

This should be able to run through fine :)

Comment: I tried with the below code using button to start program but it causes the same problem. 
`Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim NewThread = New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf Simpack.GetConnect)
        NewThread.Start()
    End Sub
End Class`

Comment: There may be a problem with the COM interface then in that case